# javascript array convert to specific format

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

The array of objects is dynamic

The activities can be four types (Idle, Down, Up, Waiting)

If the activity status is **open**, next activity status is **close** but the activity is the same.

How to convert to my expected output?

```
var arr = [
  { Activity: 'Idle', Activity_Status: 'Open', Activity_Date: "2018-09-02T12:30:00.000Z" },
  { Activity: 'Idle', Activity_Status: 'Close', Activity_Date: "2018-09-02T14:00:00.000Z"},
  { Activity: 'Down', Activity_Status: 'Open',  Activity_Date: "2018-09-02T17:30:00.000Z" },
  { Activity: 'Down', Activity_Status: 'Close', Activity_Date: "2018-09-02T19:00:00.000Z"}
]
```

Expected output is:

```
[
  { Activity: 'Idle', From: "2018-09-02T12:30:00.000Z", To: "2018-09-02T14:30:00.000Z" },
  { Activity: 'Down', From: "2018-09-02T17:30:00.000Z", To: "2018-09-02T19:00:00.000Z" }
]
```

Comment: didn't you try anything ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format a long array of js object separating dates to number and color relation to month to dates to numbers and respective colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52016473/format-a-long-array-of-js-object-separating-dates-to-number-and-color-relation-t)

Comment: i try reduce format but not get exact solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the **open** status is immediately followed by its corresponding **close** status, use a simple `for` loop, skip every other index by doing `i += 2` and for each iteration merge the current object and the next one like so:

```
var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
  result.push(
    { Activity: arr[i].Activity, From: arr[i].Activity_Date, To: arr[i + 1].Activity_Date }
  );
}
```

**Example:**

```js
var arr = [ { Activity: 'Idle', Activity_Status: 'Open', Activity_Date: "2018-09-02T12:30:00.000Z" }, { Activity: 'Idle', Activity_Status: 'Close', Activity_Date: "2018-09-02T14:00:00.000Z"}, { Activity: 'Down', Activity_Status: 'Open',  Activity_Date: "2018-09-02T17:30:00.000Z" }, { Activity: 'Down', Activity_Status: 'Close', Activity_Date: "2018-09-02T19:00:00.000Z"} ];

var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
  result.push(
    { Activity: arr[i].Activity, From: arr[i].Activity_Date, To: arr[i + 1].Activity_Date }
  );
}

console.log(result);
```

And if you want a functional way of doing it, then:

```
let result = Array.from({length: arr.length / 2}).map((_, i) =>
  ({ Activity: arr[i].Activity, From: arr[i].Activity_Date, To: arr[i + 1].Activity_Date })
);
```

**Example:**

```js
var arr = [ { Activity: 'Idle', Activity_Status: 'Open', Activity_Date: "2018-09-02T12:30:00.000Z" }, { Activity: 'Idle', Activity_Status: 'Close', Activity_Date: "2018-09-02T14:00:00.000Z"}, { Activity: 'Down', Activity_Status: 'Open',  Activity_Date: "2018-09-02T17:30:00.000Z" }, { Activity: 'Down', Activity_Status: 'Close', Activity_Date: "2018-09-02T19:00:00.000Z"} ];

let result = Array.from({length: arr.length / 2}).map((_, i) =>
  ({ Activity: arr[i].Activity, From: arr[i].Activity_Date, To: arr[i + 1].Activity_Date })
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll create an Object with key as "Activity" value, and then get the values from the result object to produce the desired output.

```js
var arr = [{
  Activity: 'Idle',
  Activity_Status: 'Open',
  Activity_Date: "2018-09-02T12:30:00.000Z"
}, {
  Activity: 'Idle',
  Activity_Status: 'Close',
  Activity_Date: "2018-09-02T14:00:00.000Z"
}, {
  Activity: 'Down',
  Activity_Status: 'Open',
  Activity_Date: "2018-09-02T17:30:00.000Z"
}, {
  Activity: 'Down',
  Activity_Status: 'Close',
  Activity_Date: "2018-09-02T19:00:00.000Z"
}]

var result = arr.reduce((mem, cur) => {
  var key = cur.Activity;
  if (mem[key]) {
    return cur['Activity_Status'] === 'Open' ? { ...mem,
        [key]: { ...mem[key],
          "From": cur['Activity_Date']
        }
      } :
      { ...mem,
        [key]: { ...mem[key],
          "To": cur['Activity_Date']
        }
      }
  } else {
    return cur['Activity_Status'] === 'Open' ? { ...mem,
        [key]: { ...mem[key],
          "From": cur['Activity_Date'],
          Activity: key
        }
      } :
      { ...mem,
        [key]: { ...mem[key],
          "To": cur['Activity_Date'],
          Activity: key
        }
      }
  }
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
var arr = [{Activity: 'Idle',
              Activity_Status: 'Open',
              Activity_Date: "2018-09-02T12:30:00.000Z" },
            {Activity: 'Idle',
              Activity_Status: 'Close',
              Activity_Date: "2018-09-02T14:00:00.000Z"}, 
            {Activity: 'Down',
              Activity_Status: 'Open',
              Activity_Date: "2018-09-02T17:30:00.000Z" },
            {Activity: 'Down',
              Activity_Status: 'Close',
              Activity_Date: "2018-09-02T19:00:00.000Z"}];

var output = [
{Activity: 'Idle', From: "", To: "" },
{Activity: 'Down', From: "", To: "" },
{Activity: 'Up', From: "", To: "" },
{Activity: 'Waiting', From: "", To: ""}
];

var i =0;
while(i < output.length){

  var j = 0;
  var activity = output[i]["Activity"];
  while(j < arr.length){

    if(arr[j]["Activity"] == activity){
    
      if(arr[j]["Activity_Status"] == "Open"){
      
      output[i]["From"] = arr[j]["Activity_Date"];
      
      }else if(arr[j]["Activity_Status"] == "Close"){
      
      output[i]["To"] = arr[j]["Activity_Date"];
      
      }
    
    }

  j++;

  }

i++;

}

console.log(output);
              
</script>
```